# Print the footer as Page X of Y when using RtfWriter2

Tags: java, pdf, itext, rtf

I am creating a .doc file using RtfWriter (itext-rtf-2.1.4.jar) & com.lowagie (itext-2.1.5).

Earlier when I was creating PDF I was able to print the footer showing "Page X of Y"  by capturing the events of closing of documents and the newpage events which is set while creating PDF in the class using the following code:

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("Sample.pdf"));

MyPageEvents events = new MyPageEvents();
writer.setPageEvent(events);
```

Where MyPageEvents is the class file that catches the events of pageending and document closing etc....on which it would set the required header and footer.

This worked very well with PDFWriter but when I started creating .doc file using RtfWriter2 it does not support the events....

```
RtfWriter2 writer = RtfWriter2.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("Sample.doc"));


MyPageEvents events = new MyPageEvents();
```

but the it does not reorganize the method writer.setPageEvents() as the PDFWriter did...

Is there a possible way around to get the footer to display Page X of Y (Here X is current page while Y is the total number of pages in the document)

Comment: RTFWriter isn't supported any more, and hasn't been for quite some time.  The guy that did all the RTF code vanished into the intarwebz years ago.

Comment: PS: "MyPageEvents" implements `PdfPageEvent`, right?  It shouldn't surprise you that it doesn't work in RTF.

Comment: So am I to believe that there is no other way to get this done with RTFWriter2..Its a shame....if its so....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah!  A quick [browsing of the source](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#T-pYbMELavA/com/lowagie/text/rtf/RtfWriter2.java&q=RtfWriter2&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc) revealed the answer:

`RtfWriter2.setHeader()` and `setFooter()`.

So something like...

```
HeaderFooter header = new HeaderFooter();
Paragraph headerP = header.paragraph();
myBuildHeader(headerP);

myRtfWriter2.setHeader(header);
```

Easy.

PS: [Google code search](http://www.google.com/codesearch) is incredibly helpful.  I can't recommend it highly enough.

---

Page X of Y?  Ah.  Well.

More [code searching](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#T-pYbMELavA/com/lowagie/text/rtf/field/RtfField.java&q=RtfWriter2&d=4) in RtfWriter2 and so forth produced `text.rtf.field.RtfPageNumber` and `text.rtf.field.RtfTotalPageNumber`.  They both extend `Chunk`.  `text.rtf.RtfHeaderFooter` can take an `Element[]` and isn't constrained to a single `Paragraph`.  Given that the page number classes both extend Chunk, that's not relevant, but is good to know For Future Reference.

My guess at the code:

```
RtfHeaderFooter footer = new RtfHeaderFooter();
Paragraph p = footer.paragraph();
p.add(new RtfPageNumber());
p.add( " of ");
p.add(new RtfTotalPageNumber());

myRtfWriter2.setFooter(footer);
```

The rest should remain identical.  I think.  I've never actually used RtfWriter2 (or RtfWriter), so don't be too shocked if this doesn't work exactly as is.

Comment: My requirement is not adding a footer or header, I have already achieved that....What I want to do is to insert a footer displaying the current page no and the total no of pages in the document(eg: if I am on the second page and there are 40 pages in the document the footer should display **PAGE 2 of 40** ).....I didn't find that in the code that you mentioned above....if its possible by the above code please elaborate it a little bit.....

Comment: Hi Mark,

You almost guesed it right just a little bit of change in the order of the code you wrote and a bit of correction did the trick...

Here is how I got it done(see the answer below), just for any future reference....
Thank You, Reallyv I apreciate your efforts thanks a lot once again......

Answer (score 1):

Well the following code will put the **"PAGE X of Y "** in the footer.

Just changed at few places in Mark's suggested code and changed the order of the code a bit and it worked beautifully....

Instead of using `writer.setFooter(footer)` to set the footer, the use of `document.setFooter(footer)` will do the trick...

```
Paragraph p=new Paragraph();
p.add( "Page  ");
p.add(new RtfPageNumber());
p.add( " of  ");
p.add(new RtfTotalPageNumber());
p.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
RtfHeaderFooter footer1 = new RtfHeaderFooter(p);
document.setFooter(footer1);
```

And A special thanks to **Mark**...he was brilliant in his code searching.....

Good Day...